# convert SQL and binding data to straight SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a custom Java query engine that produces a String of SQL (with ? as data placeholders) and a List of objects containing the data to bind to the placeholders.  This is then passed to JDBCTemplate.queryForList(sql, bindings.toArray()) API to produce a result set.

This works fine, but I also need to use this SQL in a subquery and can't figure out an (easy way) to convert from this to straight SQL (using the proper database conversion between Java types and database friendly formatting, etc).

Is there a utility to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question. So you have a SQL like this `select name from names where id=?`.  You want to use use it as a a sub query meaning - `select a.name, b.age from (select name from names where id=?) as a, age b` and a.id=b.id ?

Comment: I have "select name from names where id = ?" and List<Object> with Integer(1) and want "select name from names where id = 1.  The problem is my select stmt and List<Object> is complex with different types, etc.  I considered just doing the find/replace on my own, but it seems difficult to worry about the type mappings...

Comment: Why would you want to replace dynamic sql markers with hard coded values? I assume that's what you meant by `select name from names where id = 1` .

Comment: because I need to embed it in another SQL query (that isn't a prepared statement format)...uing iBatis specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the following utility.
http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/

While this won't answer your question directly, it might be useful in the future.  I have run into this issue as well and I devised a method that worked for me albeit not the best.  I created a method that auto fills the values from parameters as you suggested but it doesn't do it in a type-safe way at all.  Anyways, maybe you can take the method and improve upon it if you do decide to use it:

```
public static String preparedQueryString(String staticQuery, Object... parameters) {
    for(Object curParameter : parameters) {
        if(curParameter instanceof String) {
            staticQuery = staticQuery.replaceFirst("\\?", "'" + curParameter.toString() + "'");
        } else {
            staticQuery = staticQuery.replaceFirst("\\?", curParameter.toString());
        }

    return staticQuery;
}
```

You might also want to add code to make sure the number of parameters doesn't exceed the number of Question Marks and you might also want to make the java types convert more appropriately to the database your using.  I used this to output the SQL of the PreparedStatement as the PreparedStatement doesn't have any nice features that let you rip out the finished SQL query after setting the appropriate parameters.

Hope this helps,

Comment: +1 thanks, that is what I'm looking for...I was just hoping to not re-invent the wheel as I know the JDBC layer is already capable of mapping between prepared statements and SQL, etc...

Comment: Yeah, yw.  I just haven't found anything better unfortunately.  I've been looking for a while now.  I think one of the problems with the PreparedStatement is it pre-compiles the sql into the native database format and for whatever reason, can't extract the sql after the parameters have been set.  I have heard it's possible to inspect the database with tools to grab the sql query, but thats obviously not what we want either.